# Script to automatically assign max/min right Vaxis values from cells

Tags: max, min, axis, linechart

I have successfully added a script to assign vaxis max and min values from cells in my sheet.  However, I need to do the same with the RIGHT vaxis.  (the current script assigns to the left).  How can I adjust this script to work for the right as well (using cells V2 and V3 for max/min of the right vaxis).  Is this possible?  Working script below.

```
`function updateGraphRangeACTIVESHEET() {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // update hard coded values for the min/max range
  var min = dataSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var max = dataSheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  
  var chartSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // customize this if there's more than 1 chart in the sheet
  var chart = chartSheet.getCharts()[0];

  if (min == chart.getOptions().get('vAxis.minValue') && max == chart.getOptions().get('vAxis.maxValue')) {
    // do nothing if nothing changed
    return;
  }

  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options
  chart = chart
      .modify()
      .setOption('vAxis.minValue', min)
      .setOption('vAxis.maxValue', max)
      .build();
  
  chartSheet.updateChart(chart);
}`
```

I am fairly new to google scripts and not sure how to add this into the one above (which I edited from one found on stackoverflow).  Can I add something to this script, or need a second one to run?